# Count the frequency of two different values in a column that share the same value in a different column?

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have two different columns within a large transportation dataset, one with a trip id and another with a user id. How can I count the amount of times two people have ridden on the same trip together, i.e. different user id but same trip id?

```
    df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'D','A']]).T
df.columns = ['trip_id', 'user_id'] 

print(df)

   trip_id user_id
0        1       A
1        1       B
2        1       C
3        2       A
4        2       B
5        3       A
6        3       B
7        4       B
8        4       C
9        4       D
10       5       D
11       5       A
```

The ideal output would be a sort of aggregated pivot table or crosstab that displays each user_id and their count of trips with other user_id's, so as to see who has the highest counts of trips together.

I tried something like this:

```
df5 = pd.crosstab(index=df4['trip_id'], columns=df4['user_id'])
df5['sum'] = df5[df5.columns].sum(axis=1)
df5

user_id A   B   C   D   sum
trip_id                 
1     1   1   1   0      3
2     1   1   0   0      2
3     1   1   0   0      2
4     0   1   1   1      3
5     1   0   0   1      2
```

which I can use to get the average users per trip, but not the frequency of unique user_ids riding together on a trip.

I also tried some variations with this:

```
df.trip_id = df.trip_id+'_'+df.groupby(['user_id','trip_id']).cumcount().add(1).astype(str)
df.pivot('trip_id','user_id')
```

but I'm not getting what I want. I'm not sure if I need to approach this by iterating with a for loop or if I'll need to stack the dataframe from a crosstab to get those aggregate values. Also, I'm trying to avoid having the trip_id and user_id in the original data be aggregated as numerical datatypes since they should not be treated as ints but strings.

Thank you for any insight you may be able to provide!

Comment: please provide sample data and expected output

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example dataset

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B']]).T
df.columns = ['trip_id', 'user_id']

print(df)
```

Gives:

```
   trip_id user_id
0        1       A
1        1       B
2        1       C
3        2       A
4        2       B
5        2       C
6        3       A
7        3       B
8        3       C
9        3       A
10       3       B
```

I think what you're asking for is:

```
df.groupby(['trip_id', 'user_id']).size()

trip_id  user_id
1        A          1
         B          1
         C          1
2        A          1
         B          1
         C          1
3        A          2
         B          2
         C          1
dtype: int64
```

Am I correct?

Comment: I edited my question. Hopefully it is specific enough. Let me know if I need to clarify anything.